# SQLite save one to many

Tags: android, one-to-many, ormlite

Assume the following data structure.

```
    @DatabaseTable
    public class Parent {

      @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
      public int id;

      @DatabaseField
      public String name;

      @ForeignCollectionField
      public ForeignCollection<Child> child;
    }

    and the following Child Class.

    @DatabaseTable
    public class Child {

      @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
      public int id;

      @DatabaseField
      public String name;

      @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
      public Parent parent;
    }
```

By the time I want to save data I have Parent with two child.

If I do the following:

```
  parentDao.create(parent);
```

I have parent with Id and children with null parent_id

If I do

```
 childDao.create(child);
 parentDao.create(parent);
```

I have a child with null parent_id and same child with parent_id.

Is it possible to save this structure somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to create the `parent` object *first* so [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) can assign the auto-created ID.  Then you set the `parent` on the `child`'s `parent` field before you create the `child` using the `childDao`.  So something like:

```
parentDao.create(parent);
child.parent = parent;
childDao.create(child);
```

You can also use the [foreignautocreate](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-auto-create) which will automatically create the parent if it doesn't have an ID set on it.